# MySQL stored procedure will execute but conditions not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, scope, mariadb

MySQL stored procedure will execute but conditions are not working. Could someone clear up this issue?

The empty value is not checking with `or` condition. Does it need a replacement for `or`?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`rebar`@`%` PROCEDURE `SearchInProgress`(
ClientID bigint,
GCName varchar(250),
TeamID int,
USPMID Bigint,
JobReceivedDate datetime,
importanceID Bigint
)
begin
select * from jobdetails 
where 
    (clientid = ClientID or ClientID = "") and 
    (GCName = GCName or GCName ="") and
    (TeamID = TeamID or TeamID ="") and 
    (ReceivedDate = JobReceivedDate or JobReceivedDate = "") and
    (ImportanceID = importanceID or importanceID = "") and
    (JobID in (select jobid from JobCoordinatorDetails where USProjectManagerID = USPMID) );
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be brackets

This `(clientid = ClientID or ClientID = "")` could be written like this

`(clientid = ClientID) OR (ClientID = "" )`

Its justa  thought. I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE if exists SearchInProgress $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SearchInProgress`(
    aclientID bigint,
    aGCName varchar(250),
    aTeamID int,
    aUSProjectManagerID bigint,
    aReceivedDate datetime,
    aImportanceID bigint
)
begin
select * from jobdetails 
where 
    (clientid = aclientID or aclientID = '') and 
    (GCName = aGCName or aGCName = '') and
    (TeamID = aTeamID or aTeamID = '') and 
    (ReceivedDate = aReceivedDate or aReceivedDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') and
    (ImportanceID = aImportanceID or aImportanceID = '') and
    (JobID in (select jobid
                from JobCoordinatorDetails
                where USProjectManagerID = aUSProjectManagerID) or aUSProjectManagerID = '')
   ;
end
```

The parameter name and the column name must be different.  I've prepended `a` to the parameter names.

An empty datetime value is replaced by '0000-00-00 00:00:00': https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html